# How Do I Tell Which Markdown Flavor I'm Using?

Tags: yaml, markdown, openapi

With so many flavors and variations of Markdown around, how can I tell exactly which one I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI 3.1 and 3.0 use [CommonMark 0.27](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#rich-text-formatting). Tools can choose to [support additional syntax constructs](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1867#issuecomment-473134007) of top of the standard CommonMark syntax. Tools can also choose to ignore certain syntax constructs for security reasons.

OpenAPI 2.0 uses [GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM)](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#GitHub-flavored-markdown).